# Count how many times each class occurs in a dataframe

Tags: r

What is the best way to get a count of all classes in a dataframe?

I know that I could use a combination of `lapply` and `table`, but wondering if there are better ways. I am looking for an output like below.

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(lapply(iris, class))))

#     Var1 Freq
#1  factor    1
#2 numeric    4
```

Additionally, what is the best way to handle multiple classes in a dataframe? For example, using the `nycflights13`, I know I could do something like this.

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(
  lapply(nycflights13::weather, function(x)
    paste(class(x), collapse = ","))
))) %>%
  separate(col = "Var1", into = c("Var1", "Var2"), sep = ",", fill = "right")

#       Var1   Var2 Freq
#1 character   <NA>    1
#2   integer   <NA>    4
#3   numeric   <NA>    9
#4   POSIXct POSIXt    1
```

Comment: If you use `sapply` you will not need `unlist`.  Otherwise your use of `table` is probably as good as you can get _when you want tabulate something_.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Actually, because `class(x)` need not have length 1, `sapply(<list>, class)` may be a list _or_ character vector. `unlist`-`lapply` is safer. In any case, OP should be aware that `sum(Freq)` may not be equal to `length(<list>)`. (Or maybe I've just misread the question/your comment...)

Comment: Good point. While actually just this call (_i.e._ `class` over columns) quite often I guess I haven't had, say `c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")` columns.  Even though I use those fairly often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabulation of S3 classes is tricky, because:

- Objects `x` without a class attribute (such that `oldClass(x)` is `NULL`) have an implicit class (given by `class(x)`), but S3 dispatch employs an expanded class list (given by `.class2(x)` since R 4.0.0). So there are three built-in notions of class.

  ```r
  x <- .Date(0)
  oldClass(x)
  ## [1] "Date"
  class(x)
  ## [1] "Date"
  .class2(x)
  ## [1] "Date"

  y <- 0
  oldClass(y)
  ## NULL
  class(y)
  ## [1] "numeric"
  .class2(y)
  ## [1] "double"  "numeric"
  ```
- A class attribute can have any positive length, and an implicit class can have length 1 or 2 (since R 4.0.0).

  ```r
  x <- .POSIXct(0)
  oldClass(x)
  ## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
  class(x)
  ## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
  .class2(x)
  ## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

  y <- matrix(0L)
  oldClass(y)
  ## NULL
  class(y)
  ## [1] "matrix" "array"
  .class2(y)
  ## [1] "matrix"  "array"   "integer" "numeric"
  ```

So how I would tabulate the classes of variables in a list or data frame depends on:

- **How I define class.** Do I want to tabulate the result of `oldClass` (the class attribute), `class` (the class attribute if non-`NULL`, the implicit class otherwise), or `.class2` (what `UseMethod` looks at)?
- **Whether I count each variable exactly once.** Should class `c("a", "b")` count towards one or both of `"a"` and `"b"`?
- **Whether order matters.** Does my use case distinguish between classes `c("a", "b")` and `c("b", "a")`?

If I were strict about length and order, then I would probably use a function like `tabClass` below:

```r
set.seed(1L)
dd <- data.frame(x1 = seq(1L, 10L, 1L),
                 x2 = seq(1, 10, 1),
                 y1 = letters[1:10],
                 y2 = I(letters[1:10]),
                 z1 = .POSIXct(runif(10L, -1e+09, 1e+09)),
                 z2 = .POSIXct(runif(10L, -1e+09, 1e+09)))
dd$A <- replicate(3L, rnorm(10L))
```

```r
tabClass <- function(data, func) {
    cl <- vapply(data, function(x) deparse1(func(x)), "")
    tcl <- table(cl, dnn = deparse1(substitute(func)))
    as.data.frame(tcl, responseName = "count", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

tabClass(dd, oldClass)
##                 oldClass count
## 1                 "AsIs"     1
## 2 c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")     2
## 3                   NULL     4

tabClass(dd, class)
##                    class count
## 1                 "AsIs"     1
## 2            "character"     1
## 3              "integer"     1
## 4              "numeric"     1
## 5   c("matrix", "array")     1
## 6 c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")     2

tabClass(dd, .class2)
##                                     .class2 count
## 1                                    "AsIs"     1
## 2                               "character"     1
## 3                    c("double", "numeric")     1
## 4                   c("integer", "numeric")     1
## 5 c("matrix", "array", "double", "numeric")     1
## 6                    c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")     2
```

If I wanted the first column of the result to be a list of character vectors, rather than a character vector to be parsed, then I would define `tabClass` like so:

```r
tabClass <- function(data, func = class) {
    cl <- lapply(data, func)
    ucl <- unique(cl)
    setNames(data.frame(I(ucl), tabulate(match(cl, ucl), length(ucl))),
             c(deparse1(substitute(func)), "count"))
}

tabClass(dd, oldClass)
##       oldClass count
## 1                  4
## 2         AsIs     1
## 3 POSIXct,....     2

tabClass(dd, class)
##          class count
## 1      integer     1
## 2      numeric     1
## 3    character     1
## 4         AsIs     1
## 5 POSIXct,....     2
## 6 matrix, ....     1

tabClass(dd, .class2)
##        .class2 count
## 1 integer,....     1
## 2 double, ....     1
## 3    character     1
## 4         AsIs     1
## 5 POSIXct,....     2
## 6 matrix, ....     1
```

Answer (score 0):

when `df` is a data.table, I often this use this: `df[,table(sapply(.SD,class))]`. In the case of `iris`, this returns:

```
 factor numeric 
      1       4
```

Comment: Yes, that answer is equivalent to my earlier comment to Andrew that `as.data.frame(table(sapply(iris, class)))` is one step simpler.  I use `sapply` a lot for such calls or summaries.